# Does my motherboard support this NVMe SSD?

Tags: ssd, motherboard, nvme

I have an Aspire TC-710 motherboard, and I was planning to get this [NVMe M.2 SSD](https://www.samsung.com/us/computing/memory-storage/solid-state-drives/ssd-970-evo-nvme-m-2-1tb-mz-v7e1t0bw/) .

I'm really new to computers and don't know much; can I install this SSD in my motherboard?

Answer (score 1):

No.

The [official manual from Acer](https://global-download.acer.com/GDFiles/Document/User%20Manual%20W10/User%20Manual%20W10_Acer_1.0_A_A.zip?acerid=635820292677971046&Step1=DESKTOP&Step2=ASPIRE&Step3=ASPIRE%20TC-710&OS=ALL&LC=en&BC=ACER&SC=PA_6) does not provide specifications and the [Acer support page for the ATC-710](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/support-product/6393?b=1) is also missing that information.

However, [Crucial](https://www.crucial.com/usa/en/compatible-upgrade-for/Acer/aspire-tc-710) says you can't run an NVMe SSD, only SATA, confirmed by [UserBenchmark](https://www.userbenchmark.com/System/Acer-Aspire-TC-710/22241), which matches [what Ron found](https://community.acer.com/en/discussion/535936/acer-tc-710-eb61-m-2-ssd-support) in the earlier answer.

Don't spend any money on NVMe unless you can get Acer Support to confirm it works, but SATA-III SSDs are safe.

Comment: Just a note: personally I find Crucial to give false information, for example it says that my laptop `Asus N552VW` supports 32GB of RAM while in reality, the Asus docs mention that it only supports up to 16GB of RAM.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/support-product/6393;-;Aspire

type in your serial number to see motherboard specs.

you are wanting an *SSD 970 EVO **NVMe M.2** 1TB*

so you want to make sure you can plug an M.2 NVMe device in.

might be of interest: https://community.acer.com/en/discussion/535936/acer-tc-710-eb61-m-2-ssd-support

^^ they mention up to 256gb, I would email ACER support with your serial # prior to be sure prior spending $169.99.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an image of the TC-710 mobo.  On the top right, next to the power socket, is an M.2 slot.

[Picture of Acer TC710 motherboard showing location of M.2 slot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oo8GJ.jpg)